# How to retrieve checkbox value in vuejs + laravel

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuejs2, laravel-5.8

I can't retrieve the checked value in checkbox. if i changed the v-model to form.permissions[index] it will show up but if i save it it will not save.

Tried this.

```html
<table class="table table-sm">
    <tr v-for="(permission, index) in permissions" :key="permission.id">
        <td>{{ permission.name }}</td>
        <td><input type="checkbox"  class="form-check-input"  
            :value="permission.id" v-model="form.permissions[index]" checked> 
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

but this scenario will not save/update the data.

```html
<table class="table table-sm">
    <tr v-for="permission in permissions" :key="permission.id">
        <td>{{ permission.name }}</td>
        <td><input type="checkbox"  class="form-check-input"  
            :value="permission.id" v-model="form.permissions" checked></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

```
 editRow(data){
    this.editmode = true;
    this.form.reset();
    this.form.clear();
    this.form.fill(data);
    $('#addNew').modal('show');
},
```

```
for the store()
 $role = new Role();
 $role->name = $request['name'];
 $role->ident = $request['ident'];
 $role->description = $request['description'];
 $role->level = $request['level'];
 $role->active = $request['active'];
 $role->save();

 $role = Role::find($role->id);
 $role->permissions()->attach($request['permissions']);
 return $role;

for update()
 $role = Role::findOrFail($id);
 $role->name = $request['name'];
 $role->ident = $request['ident'];
 $role->description = $request['description'];
 $role->level = $request['level'];
 $role->active = $request['active'];
 $role->permissions()->sync($request['permissions']);
 $role->update();
```

it must save and update the data and retrieve the old value.

Answer (score 1):

Try `:checked="form.permissions[index]"` get rid of the `v-model`

Comment: the saving is not saving and updating if using this.

Comment: what is the code that is saving? are you reffering to front end code? vue? where?

Comment: no. i use laravel as backend. i put it there. from my front-end i use api.